# Debian doesn't show wifi connection

Tags: debian, wifi

I installed debian on an old Toshiba laptop and did everything through LAN. But now I saw that wifi is totally missing. Searching online I found that my output of `pci -nn | grep -i network` might be useful:

```
06:02.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation PRO/Wireless 2200BG [Calexico2] Network Connection [8086:4220] (rev 05)
```

I tried to re-install wireless-tools and firmware-iwlwifi and network-manager but nothing works, help me please. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Wifi card you're using is in a series *before* the Intel cards called "legacy" ([3945 / 4965](https://wiki.debian.org/iwlegacy)). They have their own Debian wiki page: [ipw2200](https://wiki.debian.org/ipw2200):

> **ipw2200**
>
> The following list is based on the alias fields of `modinfo ipw2200` in
> Debian 3.16 (3.16.7-ckt9-3~deb8u1) kernel images.
>
> ```
> PCI: 8086:1043 Intel Corporation PRO/Wireless LAN 2100 3B Mini PCI Adapter
> PCI: 8086:104F Intel Corporation (Device name unknown)
> PCI: 8086:4220 Intel Corporation PRO/Wireless 2200BG [Calexico2] Network Connection
> PCI: 8086:4221 Intel Corporation (Device name unknown)
> PCI: 8086:4223 Intel Corporation PRO/Wireless 2915ABG [Calexico2] Network Connection
> PCI: 8086:4224 Intel Corporation PRO/Wireless 2915ABG [Calexico2] Network Connection
> ```

Your card appears in the list (or in a probably more up-to-date list at the [end of this link](https://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/IPW2200.html)).

Its firmware isn't provided by `firmware-iwlwifi` but by [`firmware-ipw2x00`](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/firmware-ipw2x00).

Once installed, as documented you should remove and reload the kernel module to avoid a reboot:

> ```
> # modprobe -r ipw2200; modprobe ipw2200
> ```

If that's not enough, verify that there's no keyboard switch disabling the card, or (if support exists for this old hardware) install and use the [`rfkill`](https://manpages.debian.org/rfkill/rfkill.8) command.

The corresponding network interface should now appear in `ip link`'s output.

Comment: Debian wiki updated.

Comment: Thank you a lot. Everything is working fine now. And yes, there was indeed a switch on the keyboard.